# IWebPreferences for each WebView

Tags: c++, webkit, webview, image-loading

I am trying to disable image auto loading of some WebViews while I keep others enabled. However when I disable it for a WebView, all webviews stop loading image. Below is code I use:

```
IWebPreferences *prefs = NULL;
webView->preferences(&prefs);
prefs->setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
prefs->Release();
```

What is the proper way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use different identifier for each webview using *initWithIdentifier*